# Python Logger printing two times

Tags: python, logging

Here is the code I have and it is printing logs two time
```

```
def get_logger(name, verbose=False):
  # create logger
  logger = logging.getLogger(name)

  # create console handler and set level to debug
  ch = logging.StreamHandler()

  if verbose:
      logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
      ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
  else:
      logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
      ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)

  # create formatter
  formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : [%(name)s] : %(levelname)s : %(message)s')

  # add formatter to ch
  ch.setFormatter(formatter)

  # add ch to logger
  logger.addHandler(ch)
  return logger
```

```

Not sure why is it printing two times on the screen. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. so there is a small change required in the logger which can solved the issue. Here is the new code:
```

```
   def get_logger(self):
        # create logger
        logger = logging.getLogger(self.name)
        logger.propagate = False  #### ------- ADDED --------- #####

        # create console handler and set level to debug
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()

        if self.verbose:
            logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        else:
            logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
            ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        # create formatter
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : [%(name)s] : %(levelname)s : %(message)s')

        # add formatter to ch
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)

        # add ch to logger
        logger.addHandler(ch)
        return logger
```

```